# Draw on top of video with AxWindowsMediaPlayer

Tags: c#, winforms

I try to draw eye tracking data on a video with WinForms AxWindowsMediaPlayer. I do not use WPF. I tried some things, but nothing worked.

This one draws over the control, but when the video starts, the video overlays it again:

```
Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);
Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);

Graphics g = windowsMediaPlayer.CreateGraphics();
g.DrawRectangle(pen, eyeX, eyeY, 5, 5);

g.DrawLine(pen, 0, 0, 2000, 2000);
```

I also tried transparent controls, but it's the same with them. They get overlayed by the video.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is `WindowlessVideo` property. You need to enable it in order to draw or show something over video.

```
windowsMediaPlayer.WindowlessVideo = true
```

read more here [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562473(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562473%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

a note from the link above

> By default, an embedded Windows Media Player control renders video in its own window within the client area. When windowlessVideo is set to true, the Windows Media Player object renders video directly in the client area, so you can apply special effects or layer the video with text.
>   In Windows Vista, rendering video in windowless mode can degrade performance.

Comment: Unfortunately the drawing is overlayed by the video when it starts to play.

Comment: This doesn't seem to make any difference.